# Get value of xml child node by name attribute

Tags: c#

I am trying to pull data from an XML document that is stored on a user's pc. I would want to pull items such as Password, Username, Panelload, & DemonLoad.

XML:

```
    <userSettings>
        <Refreshe.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
                <value>aaa</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Username" serializeAs="String">
                <value>bbb</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="PanelLoad" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DemonLoad" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="DiscordRPC" serializeAs="String">
                <value>True</value>
            </setting>
        </Refreshe.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
```

C# Code:

```
        static void getRebirthInfo()
        {

            var vbls = new variables();

            // get list of files in root directory and all its subdirectories
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(vbls.rootdir, "*.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


            // get number of config files
            int fileCount = files.Length;

            //prints out each config fie (debugging use only)
            Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, files));

            //Create the XmlDocument instance
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();


            // load each xml doc
            for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++)
            {
                doc.Load(files[i]);
                var RefreshePassword = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Refreshe.Properties.Settings").SelectSingleNode("setting").InnerText;


            }
          

        }
```

I have tried multiple methods and been having trouble. I always seem to get the same error as well...

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Line 43
```

Line 43 would be

```
var RefreshePassword = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Refreshe.Properties.Settings").SelectSingleNode("setting").InnerText;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq with a dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("Refreshe.Properties.Settings").FirstOrDefault().Elements("setting")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("name"), y => (string)y.Element("value"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the values of specific nodes, do this (getting 'Password' in this case):

```
var xml =
@"<userSettings>
    <Refreshe.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name=""Password"" serializeAs=""String"">
            <value> aaa </value>
        </setting>
        <setting name=""Username"" serializeAs=""String"">
            <value> bbb </value>
        </setting>
            <setting name=""PanelLoad"" serializeAs=""String"">
        <value> False </value>
        </setting>
        <setting name=""DemonLoad"" serializeAs=""String"">
            <value> False </value>
        </setting>
        <setting name=""DiscordRPC"" serializeAs=""String"">
            <value> True </value>
        </setting>
        </Refreshe.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>";

var xdoc=new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

var settingName = "Password";
var xpath = $"*/setting[@name='{settingName}']/value";
var refreshPasswordElement = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode(xpath);
var refreshPasswordValue = refreshPasswordElement?.InnerText;
```

...and to get the value of all settings, do this:

```
var xpath = "*/setting";
foreach (XmlNode setting in xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(xpath))
{
    var parsedSetting =
        new
        {
            Name = setting.Attributes["name"].InnerText,
            Value = setting.FirstChild.InnerText
        };
    //do stuff
}
```